# Android processes behavior

Tags: android, process

I couldn't find any explanation on how android actually creates new process. 
To be more precise, this is how I create the process on androidManifest:

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".myService" android:process=":myService"/>
```

and I want to know what this new process contains? does it copies the whole image of the main process (code and other resources) or it starts as a "clean page"? (iv'e notice its replicating the Application but it feels like it is keeping more than that)

Comment: Check out the docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: I've already read that. It doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for that:

1. Create a static variable:

   ```
   public class SameProcessFlag {
       public static boolean sameProcess = false;
   }
   ```
2. Before starting the service, set it to true:

   ```
    SameProcessFlag.sameProcess = true
   ```
3. Let the started process check the flag in, say, *onCreate()*

   ```
   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       Log.d("~~~~","\n\n\n\n\n~~~ SameProcessFlag.sameProcess = "+SameProcessFlag.sameProcess+"\n\n\n\n\n");
   }
   ```

   Use `adb logcat | grep '~~~~'` to remove noise from the logcat output.
4. Post here the result of this experiment.

PS

5. If still in doubt, repeat the experiment with open input streams.

Comment: I can't control the service start time, look at what I wrote in the androidManifest (it is stating automatically).

Comment: Yes you can. Just startService() from an Activity in addition to what you have. When your freshly built package is installed, the old service will be killed. Or create a separate test project.

Comment: BTW as to "starting automatically", are you sure it gets started at all? Because "starting automatically" usually means via a _BroadcastReceiver_ that explicitly invokes _Context.startService()_